# Does Claw compromise anonymity provided by Tails?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, tails, email

I'd like to know if anonymity is comprised while setting Claw with my everyday mail addresses (name.surname@gmail, hotmail).

My first thought would answer yes, but i'm not expert.

if so, what could you advise me to keep all the benefits from tails about mail?

Thanks for reading,

best regards for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course, if you specify your say who you are. It is like wearing a mask and telling someone who you are.

The benefit of using Tor in such a scenario would be to make it harder for someone to find out where you are (if you don't mail photos or disclose your location otherwise). So you might make it harder for your Gmail or Hotmail to track your behavior.

If you want to replace anonymity with pseudonymity an option would be to create a new account with some pseudonym (and not your real name/data) and never use your other address on TAILS. If you choose a provider that requires you to receive a text message you might want to use a prepaid card. Even though then someone obtaining a cell phone tower dump will at least have a location associated with the account.

Also keep in mind that you must not ever use that email address outside of Tor or your anonymity will be compromised, including everything that was ever sent.

Also keep in mind that even when you have TLS/SSL enabled email is not end to end encrypted, so your email provider will still be able to read the content of your emails.

If you want anonymity in emails though the best option might be to use [anonymous remailers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_remailer). They use a system similar to Tor and can be combined with Tor. Their major downside is that they are slower than normal email and that there are not so many users, so you might stand out using it, which is why using it over Tor might be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for that bunch of tips and intel. They give me clear directions about what to do and what not to.